# Compare if order of elements matches in 2 XML files with Schematron

Tags: xml, xpath, schematron

I want to compare two XML files using Schematron. I have a template that looks as follows:

```
  <action name="thirdAction" id="3">      
<return-values>
  <return-value name="communication-profile-id" />
  <return-value name="messaging-profile-id" />
</return-values>
```

And when one creates an instance of the action it looks something like this:

```
  <instanceOfAction name="thirdAction" id="3">     
    <results>
     <result name="communication-profile-id" />
     <result name="messaging-profile-id" />
    </results>
 </instanceOfAction>
```

I want to map the instanceOfAction to the given action based on the id and then check if the child elements' names correspond. In my hierarchy I have a lot of actions which makes this more difficult. Does somebody have a suggestion for implementing this? I succeeded checking to see if the results in the instanceOfAction are in SOME defined action, but not specifically in the action with the same id, by doing the following:

```
   <sch:rule context="//ts:instanceOfAction/ts:results/ts:result">  
      <sch:assert test="$testspecification//(ts:actions/ts:action/ts:return-values/ts:return-value)[@name= current()/@key]">
        The keys from the results do not match with the names from the return-values.
      </sch:assert>
    </sch:rule>
```

where the variable $testspecification is the path to the root hierarchy, which contains all the XML files.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an xPath predicate to find the matching `action`, like you did to find the matching `return-value`. You can use `..` to go up a level (or use the `ancestor::` axis).

```
<sch:rule context="//ts:instanceOfAction/ts:results/ts:result">  
  <sch:assert test="$testspecification//ts:actions/ts:action[@id= current()/../../@id]/ts:return-values/ts:return-value[@name= current()/@key]">
    The keys from the results do not match with the names from the return-values.
  </sch:assert>
</sch:rule>
```

The weakness of the rule as written above is that it will not catch cases where `results` is missing a `result` specified by the template. If I were writing the rule, I might approach it by setting the context to be `ts:instanceOfAction`, and then use asserts to verify that `instanceOfAction` contains everything specified by `Action`, like this:

```
<sch:rule context="ts:instanceOfAction">  
  <sch:assert test="every $returnValue in $testspecification//ts:actions/ts:action[@id= current()/@id]/ts:return-values/ts:return-value satisfies $returnValue/@name = current()/ts:results/ts:result/@name and
                    every $result in ts:results/ts:result satisfies $result/@name = $testspecification//ts:actions/ts:action[@id= current()/@id]/ts:return-values/ts:return-value/@name">
    The keys from the results should match with the names from the return-values.
  </sch:assert>
</sch:rule>
```

(I haven't tested the above sample, so it might require some modification.)

From the question title, it sounds like you might also be interested in asserting that the `result` elements are in the correct sequence compared to the template. You can use the XPath `position()` function to help check that.